# SQLiteOpenHelper AndroidStudio problem with writableData - Kotlin

Tags: sqlite, android-studio, kotlin

all!

I have written a piece of code and whenever it reaches specific line, my program crashes.
The line I am having problem with is:

```
val db = this.writableDatabase
```

I have also tried with:

```
val db = super.getWritableDatabase()
```

And it always crashes.

Here is the code:

```
private val DB_NAME      = "Keys DB"
private val TABLE_NAME   = "Keys Table"
private val COL_ID       = "id"
private val COL_VALS     = "number of keys"

class DBHelpCreate(var context : Context) : SQLiteOpenHelper (context, DB_NAME,null,1)
{
    override fun onCreate (db : SQLiteDatabase?)
    {

        val generate = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                        COL_ID       + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                        COL_VALS     + "INTEGER)"
        db?.execSQL(generate)
    }

    override fun onUpgrade (db : SQLiteDatabase?, oldVersion : Int, newVersion : Int)
    {
        /* Not implemented. */
    }

    fun add_data(counter: CountKeys)
    {
        val db = this.writableDatabase
        var cv = ContentValues()

        ...
    }
 }
```

//`some activity`

```
var db = DBHelpCreate(this)
db.add_data(CountKeys ())
```

Does anybody see what is wrong?

Comment: And what is written in logcat?

Comment: Spaces are not allowed in table/column names. So change the names or use square brackets to enclose them: `private val TABLE_NAME   = "[Keys Table]"` `private val COL_VALS     = "[number of keys]"`

Comment: @forpas, thank you! This solved the problem.